# How do I transfer epub files from iMac to Samsung Galaxy Tab 4?

Tags: macos, mac, android

Have 2 iMacs, one running 10.10.1, the other 10.4.11. My old Nook can be plugged into either, and I can drag-and-drop my epubs onto my Nook. Just got a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 Nook. No longer able to drag-and-drop with new device. Uploaded some epubs through Dropbox, and then downloaded them to the Galaxy. Problem is they end up in the Galaxy's Dropbox folder. I can open the files to read them, but I am unable to transfer them to the Nooks library. If I download dozens of books, I am unable to sort through them by title/author etc. with the Nook, and am forced to scroll through them in the Dropbox folder every time I want to read a book.

Is there any way to have the Galaxy actually show up on the iMac, so I can drag-and-drop the epubs into it. If not, is there a way to transfer the downloaded epub files from the Dropbox folder into the Nook reader, so I can actually use the reader to search for and organize my epubs. Or should I just return the Galaxy and get an iPad?? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've had success getting all kinds of media moved between Mac and Android using [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en). I don't have a Nook so I'm not sure what folder would work best but you can choose where to drop the files on your Galaxy.  I've had mixed results using Google's [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) but that's another option you can look into.

HTH